# How to change status of a mongoose entry on time expiry?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, datetime, express, mongoose

When I am requesting an api `/user/getItems`, It should return me all Items having status `expired` or  `active`.

`Item` is our mongoose Schema having properties

`status` , `expiryTime`

Now,

```
var timeNow = moment().toDate();
Item.find({expiryTime: $gte: timeNow})
    .exec(function(err, returnItems){
   //Returns Deals whose expiry Time is larger than the current time.
}
```

Now I want to change the status of `Item`to `expired` when the

```
expiryTime < timeNow
```

How should we exactly go about this problem? There should be a trigger on the expire event instead of comparing `expiryTime` with `timeNow` on everyrequest or say every 5 minutes.

It should trigger an event spontaneously once the item's

```
expiryTime < timeNow
```

Thanks in Advance. Cheers!

Comment: To make a long story short: MongoDB does not have any triggers except TTL indices. But if you have an expiry time present in the data, you can easily check wether an item is expired or not. And you can easily query for non-expired items. So why make something complicated?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg So everytime I receive an API Call, I check for all items for their `expiryTime` against `timeNow` and update status of each Item?

Comment: Why would you want to update their status? a query like `db.collection.find({expiryTime:{$gt: new ISODate()}})` would give you all non-expired entries, while `db.collection.find({expiryTime:{$lt: new ISODate()}})` would give you all expired.

Comment: Yes. Wanted them for Reporting purposes else where, shall use the same `db.collection.find({expiryTime:{$lt: new ISODate()}})` to do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already written in the comments, there is no reason the change a status. Given this example structure

```
{
  someField: "Some value!"
  expiryDate: <some ISODate()>
}
```

you can easily find all expired documents with

```
db.collection.find( { expiryDate: { $lt: new ISODate() } } )
```

and all non-expired documents with

```
db.collection.find( { expiryDate: { $gt: new ISODate() } } )
```

In order to keep the collection small or move expired documents to a more appropriate collection, you can do this in a mongo shell:

```
var cut = new ISODate()
db.collection.aggregate(
  [ { $match: { expiryDate: { $lt: cut } } } ],
  { out: "moreAppropriateCollection" }
)
db.collection.remove( { expiryDate: { $lt: cut } } )
```